# set text value from fragment.newInstance String

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to set a string to a textview but everytime i click the button Quiz the activity is just refreshing instead going to fragment activity.

This summarize the situation.

1. I have dynamic viewPager inside activity called Quiz_Container
2. Use only one fragment(Module_Topics_Content_Quiz) in  public Fragment getItem(int position) or FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
3. I want to change text of a textview in the fragment from activity everytime i swipe.
4. I am passing the string using newInstance with parameter from activity to fragment
5. The string came from quizQuestion.get(position)
6. I'm getting the right value with the Log.d but when setting it to textview the activity is just refreshing.

this is my code.

Quiz_Container.java

```
public class Quiz_Container extends AppCompatActivity implements Module_Topics_Content_Quiz.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;

    ViewPager quizPager;

    private int topicID;
    private int moduleID;
    private int subModuleID;

    private ArrayList<Integer> quizID;
    private ArrayList<String> quizQuestion;
    private ArrayList<String> choiceA;
    private ArrayList<String> choiceB;
    private ArrayList<String> choiceC;
    private ArrayList<String> choiceD;
    private ArrayList<String> quizAnswer;


    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz__container);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Quiz");
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f1ad1e")));



        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        topicID = extras.getInt("topicID");
        moduleID = extras.getInt("moduleID");
        subModuleID = extras.getInt("subModuleID");

        Log.d("quizTopicID", "" + topicID);
        Log.d("quizModuleID", "" + moduleID);
        Log.d("quizSubModuleID", "" + subModuleID);

        new quizTask().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } // Check Internet Connection

    class quizTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL quizURL = new URL("http://192.168.1.110/science/index.php/users/get_quiz_items/" + topicID + "/" + moduleID + "/" + subModuleID + "" );

                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)quizURL.openConnection();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String quizResponse;

                while ((quizResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    return  quizResponse;

                }

                return sb.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if(reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return  null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String quizResponses) {

            Log.d("quizResponse", "" + quizResponses);

            try {
                JSONObject quizObject = new JSONObject(quizResponses);

                boolean result = quizObject.getBoolean("success");

                if (result) {

                    JSONArray quizArray = quizObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    quizID = new ArrayList<>();
                    quizQuestion = new ArrayList<>();
                    choiceA = new ArrayList<>();
                    choiceB = new ArrayList<>();
                    choiceC = new ArrayList<>();
                    choiceD = new ArrayList<>();
                    quizAnswer = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < quizArray.length(); i ++) {

                        JSONObject dataQuiz = quizArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        quizID.add(dataQuiz.getInt("id"));
                        quizQuestion.add(dataQuiz.getString("question"));
                        choiceA.add(dataQuiz.getString("a"));
                        choiceB.add(dataQuiz.getString("b"));
                        choiceC.add(dataQuiz.getString("c"));
                        choiceD.add(dataQuiz.getString("d"));
                        quizAnswer.add(dataQuiz.getString("answer"));

                    }

                    Log.d("quizSize", "" + quizID.size());

                    quizPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.quizPager);
                    fragmentManager = Quiz_Container.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    quizPager.setAdapter(new quizAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
                    quizPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "no quiz yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    } // end of quizTask

    class quizAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public quizAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < quizID.size; i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    fragment = Module_Topics_Content_Quiz.newInstance(quizQuestion.get(position));
                    Log.d("testQuestion", "" + quizQuestion.get(position)); // this code is working
                }
            }
            return fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return quizID.size();
        }
    }

}
```

Module_Topics_Content_Quiz.java

```
public class Module_Topics_Content_Quiz extends Fragment {

    TextView textQuizQuestion;

    private String qQuestion;


    public Module_Topics_Content_Quiz() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public static Module_Topics_Content_Quiz newInstance(String question) {
        Module_Topics_Content_Quiz fragment = new Module_Topics_Content_Quiz();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("question", question);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            qQuestion = getArguments().getString("question");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_module__topics__content__quiz, container, false);

        textQuizQuestion = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);

        Log.d("question", "" + qQuestion); // this is working
//        textQuizQuestion.setText(qQuestion); // error if enable
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fragment, try inflating the `TextView` using the `View` returned rather than using `getActivity()`

You need to inflate the Fragment's view and call `findViewById()` on the `View` it returns.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_module__topics__content__quiz, container, false);

        // inflate the View inside Fragment using the View returned
        textQuizQuestion = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);

        Log.d("question", "" + qQuestion); // this is working
        textQuizQuestion.setText(qQuestion);
        return rootView;
    }
```

You can also use `getView()` from within the Fragment to get the root view.

If you wanna call from the enclosing Activity, use

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id).getView().findViewById(R.id.your_view);
```